# PPP protocol is consuming so much data

Tags: internet, ppp, modem

I am using PPP protocol with a LTE modem. I do not have any other specific application running, and in 20 hours ppp0 protocol has consumed 53MB (19MB in Rx and 34MB in Tx). Is not this so much?? Which could be the problem? Is there any way to monitor which application is consuming this data?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Compared to [12GB per day on Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/1163852/windows-10-400-gb-network-data-on-system-in-the-past-30-days), 53MB in 20 hours seems pretty modest.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: which ended up being malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is not this so much??

It depends what are you doing on your Raspberry.

> Is there any way to monitor which application is consuming this data?

You can use [`nethogs`](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) to check which application is currently using your internet bandwidth.